# Dealloc method of UIView subclass not getting called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, memory-management

I have a view controller named SettingsViewController, and a custom UIView subclass named ViewAccounts. In SettingsViewController, I am using the code below to add ViewAccounts view into SettingsViewController.

```
 if(!self.viewAccounts)
 {
      ViewAccounts *objViewAccounts= [[ViewAccounts alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yViews, 320, 400) withViewController:self];
      [self.view insertSubview:objViewAccounts atIndex:0];
      self.viewAccounts = objViewAccounts;
      [objViewAccounts release];
}
```

The Problem is that the dealloc method of  ViewAccounts (subclass of UIView) is not getting called. If I comment these both lines of code, then dealloc method gets called.

```
[self.view insertSubview:objViewAccounts atIndex:0];
self.viewAccounts = objViewAccounts;
```

I guess the problem is  with retain count, at it gets incremented by 1 when we use insertSubview or addSubiew, but how to get rid of it. Is this the right approach to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a note: making **viewAccount** to assign can cause a Zombie down the road (in the original code snippet) because you release it in the last line.

I would suggest the following approach:

1. Make viewAccounts **retain** again
2. Don't use autorelease because you are not returning it from that method
3. Pay attention to **dealloc** method of the method in the snippet

This is how I would write the snippet with **viewAccounts** retaining

```
if(!self.viewAccounts)
{
  ViewAccounts *objViewAccounts= [[ViewAccounts alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yViews, 320, 400) withViewController:self];
  [self.view addSubview:objViewAccounts];
  self.viewAccounts = objViewAccounts;
  [objViewAccounts release];
}
...
- (void) dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [viewAccounts release];
    ...
}
```

What happened in your original code was that the retaining variable **viewAccounts** was not released properly at the end of the this class life cycle and so dealloc was not called.

BTW when you only **assign** the variable then you have to manage the retain yourself if you **re-assign** that variable especially if you NIL it. Assume that you set the variable to NIL then the snippet could be executed again. But then you overwrite the variable and you are **not able** to release the first value. If you use **retain** the Object-C will do that for you. As a rule of thumb I would always use **retain** for properties until you have enough experience to handle the other cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for great information. Since after I used assign, app was quitting. Now it is working fine. Just to make sure, if we retain a property, in dealloc method, should one use self.anyProperty = nil or just [anyProperty release] or both?

Answer (score 0):

You could set your objViewAccounts to autorelease, since it will be retained by self.view anyway.

```
ViewAccounts *objViewAccounts= [[[ViewAccounts alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yViews, 320, 400) withViewController:self] autorelease];
```

Also regarding the retain count, if the property self.viewAccounts is declared as retain, that would also increase the retain count by 1.

Comment: Thanks. The property self.viewAccounts was declared as retain. Now I have changed it to assign. autorelease did not make any difference, as I guess, it just decreases the retain count by 1. I think the release method also does the same thing, except that we call it explicitly. I am not sure, why assign did the trick. Anyway thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem :), well that is because assign does not increase retain count.